# Handling Incoming Request URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-parsing

Currently trying to augment the search of an existing ASP.NET site. My background is Java, so if I was writing a server in Java, I could just handle the incoming request as a string and parse it however I wanted, taking out the search terms, etc.

What part of ASP handles that? Where should I be looking for where the incoming string is taken apart to handle the search request? There is a search button which redirects the page to a URL which includes the search parameters. That's where the trail goes cold for me as I need to know where it comes back into the server.

For example, once you've vetted the search term it gets submitted like this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/shop?" + type + "=" + searchBoxContent);
```

'type' is the type of search so that could be based on brand or searching within the product description, etc.

The site is already using some type of url rewriting as the url doesn't show up with any .aspx when you do a search. Should I be looking in a config file or a .master.cs file or where to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET Webforms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @ekad It's Webforms. It is an existing project so I don't really have the option of going for MVC, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried using a HttpModule for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest system for this is ASP.NET MVC which has a built-in Route and parameter handler.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) for docs.

Example:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Can redirect to a Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Find(int id)
{ ... }
```

If this is not what you want, take a look at [this blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) of Scott Guthrie on URL rewriting.

Comment: +1 for the blog post. The answer is probably in there some place but I'll probably just have to ask the guy who originally wrote it where he put the code that handles the searches because it could be accessed in multiple locations. I agree that MVC would probably be the better option but I'm tied to this wagon for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a URL like this:

```
/shop.aspx?type=abc
```

then you can use [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the get the value of `type`. This is the syntax:

```
Request.QueryString["type"]
```

For example if you want to get the value when `/shop.aspx?type=abc` is loaded at the first time, then you should add this code in `Page_Load` method inside the code behind (`shop.aspx.cs`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // assign 'type' query string to typeOfSearch
        string typeOfSearch = Request.QueryString["type"];
    }
}
```

Comment: This forces the OP to use shop.aspx as you already state, but nonetheless +1.

Comment: I realize now I probably asked an impossible question as there doesn't seem to be the critical 'fork in the road' where ASP deals with request URLs as it may happen in other frameworks.

Comment: @ekad Thanks for your input but I have to deal with an existing application so I don't have the freedom to do as you suggest. I just need to track down the existing code and modify it. That's my problem right now is I can't find the part where it is already being handled.

Comment: @GenericJam you can try to check web.config and see if there's any rewrite rules, or check global.asax in `Application_BeginRequest` method, maybe the url rewrite is in either of them.